# How can I delete all alerts for a user in Sharepoint 2007 without visiting every site?

Tags: 2007, alert, powershell

A user leaves the organisation.  Their account is removed from active directory.  Their user object does not get removed from Sharepoint, and their alerts remain in place.  This generates undeliverable messages each time an alert is sent to the email address in Sharepoint.

How can I tidy up all the alerts for a given user, without having to visit each site and remove the alerts for that user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I created a script to do this using PowerShell](http://www.dunxd.com/2010/12/delete-all-alerts-for-a-user-in-sharepoint-with-this-powershell-script/).  Comments appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a powershell expert, but it seems a sensible approach. My only thought is I'd have iterated over all Web Apps. I mean, if they've been removed from AD, they've been removed from all web apps, right?

Your way is probably more efficient, though.

Comment: Good point - I'll have to update the script at some point to do this in one step.

Answer (score 0):

Go to /_layouts/mysubs.aspx page and manage your alerts.

Comment: We have over 100 site collections with numerous subsites.  A user may have setup an alert in any of 500 places.  There is no central place to view these - so it is impractical to scour every single place an alert can be set up each time a user leaves the organisation.  That is the problem I am trying to solve.